# recommending books for GRE math subject test

Tags: reference-request, gre-exam

I wonder if anyone could recommend some books (other than Princeton Review) to prepare for the GRE math subject exam. I've heard that the REA books have lots of typos, though it has 6 practice exams. So I am really looking for the books with some practice exams, but needs to be well-written.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91170/books-to-study-for-math-gre-self-study-have-some-time?rq=1)

Comment: What is an REA book?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

REA books or Princeton review are not so useful.

1. Make sure that you do each and every problem from Stewart Calculus atleast twice, since its timed test, pace is also important factor.
2. Do Dummit upto field extensions, if you have time do Artin's Algebra too.
3. Rudin Real Analysis, Munkres Topology, Insel Linear Algebra are also must.
4. I suggest to go for Gamlin Complex Analysis, Brown's Complex Analysis is also sufficient but if you are good at Complex Analysis you can save time in the exam by simplifying integral using methods from Complex Analysis. (Do till Residues)
5. For the misc topics pick any Discrete Maths book and read them a day or two that's more than enough.
6. Learn some basic number theory from any introductory book.
7. Do all the 4 available practice tests, you should be able to finish of the tests little earlier because actual test will be harder than those practice tests.

These are the books I can recollect now, if possible I will update later with other books if any.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer! but do every problem from stewart calculus? is that really a good strategy...

Comment: I can't reveal more details due to GRE policy, but that suggestion comes from my experience, I concentrated little on Stewart Calculus, but it turned to be a grave mistake, but if you don't have much time at least do every thing from multivariable calculus atleast twice and other part atleast once.

Comment: @K.Dutta, I don't know your mail id. You can ask your questions here or you can initiate a chat.

Comment: @Ram you said you cannot reveal due to gre policy . can you tell me what is it?

Comment: Can you please tell me as to which version Stewart calculus book will be? @Ram

Comment: @Ram  I haven't studied complex analysis as a course. So if I am to read Gamlin or Brown's upto which chapter do you suggest I should read? Also in Munkres Topology and Rudin real analysis how far should I read?

Comment: @sam_rox Good question. I'm about to ask. How did it go for you anyway?

Comment: Ram and @sam_rox, what's the coverage for Munkres Topology? Asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2780653) and [here](http://www.mathematicsgre.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=4552)what's the coverage for Munkres Topology? Asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2780653) and [here](http://www.mathematicsgre.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=4552). I read that it's up to Chapter 6. Just wanna make sure. Others say Chapter 3.

Comment: Hey @Ram I need to take the GRE subject test in two months from now. I am a theoretical physicist with a master degree at ETH. Would you give me the precise references for these book you mentioned?
Moreover, do you think it is possible to do a good result (top 10%) with a full-time study if I start as soon as possible? I would have the October session as well.

Thank you very much!

Comment: In particular for Dummit and Steward. @Ram

Comment: @Bellem subject GRE is not a big deal in applications, I know many people get into decent schools with poor GRE scores. It is hard to say whether you can get 90 percentile score or not without knowing more about your background. Take a look at ETS practice tests and see how well you can score in those, which will give you an idea. My post above contains all references if you have any question about a specific  reference, I am happy to answer.

Comment: @Ram hey, thanks a lot. I saw and can say that now I would score definitely poor. The thing is that I forgot some basic stuff, or at least I would say it takes me some time to figure it out. I should need some practice. I have got three published paper and an over average (not super though) final mark. I think I should do a fabulous GRE score to get in a top tier one. Anyways, the references for the GRE in 2020 are the same you gave in this post? In particular, what are the complete names for for Dummit and Steward?
Thanks mate!

Comment: @Bellem Stewart's calculus and Dummit and Foote Abstract Algebra.

Comment: @Ram found on Libgen thanks!

Comment: Lol, "Insel linear algebra" is the name of an actual book?

Answer (score 6):

This test is 90% on calculus or precalculus. I did not do well but my friends who spend one month reviewing Stewart got perfect mark rather easily. So try to work on as many dumb problems as possible in Stewart's book, it will help.

In case you decided to go to graduate school, it will help you in TA sesions as well. Before the test, the undergraduate students will ask you three question in a minute and you have to sketch a proof for any problem to them in 20 seconds. In my case the department advisor just  sent me to the math helproom and claimed I can help any student in any subject whatsoever, and that is my experience of life as a teaching assistant.

Comment: Can you please tell me as to which Stewart calculus book it is? I see different versions of it.

Comment: I just took the GRE exam earlier today, I think they may have changed it a bit, though calculus was the most frequent topic, it was no where near 90% of the exam. Lots of questions from basic real anlaysis actually.